# Image is missing required "src" property (JEST)

Tags: image, jestjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm getting this error

> Image is missing required "src" property. Make sure you pass "src" in props to the `next/image` component.

I already tried to call the src import on file, put the import directly on src instead of importing, absolute imports and many other things. I have no idea what's causing this and my only hope are that its a config missing.

```js
import WhiteLabel from '@components/About/WhiteLabel';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-libraty/jest-dom';
import {whiteLabelList} from '@utils'

describe("whiteLabel component",() => {
  it('should return if the list topics is in the document',()=>{
    const { getByText } = render(<WhiteLabel />);

    whiteLabelList.forEach(object => {
      expect(getByText(object.text)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
})
```

**WhiteLabel Component**

```js
import imageSrc from "../../public/images/imageSrc.svg";

        <Image
          width={700}
          height={560}
          src={imageSrc}
          alt="White Label"
          draggable={false}
        />
```

The error occurs in the render method, so nothing under it gets executed:

[image]

Comment: Can we see the usage inside of the component (WhiteLabel) that is using the next image component?

Comment: I edited the question and put it in the usage inside the WhiteLabel component